# Output of 3 queries

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Got this 3 in 1 query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT mesures.date j, AVG(mesures.valeur) maxi 
FROM mesures
JOIN plages_horaire ON mesures.id_plage = plages_horaire.id_plage 
WHERE MONTH(mesures.date) = '9' AND YEAR(mesures.date) = '2016' AND mesures.code_station = 'P02SE' AND mesures.id_crit = '1' AND mesures.id_type = '1' 
GROUP BY mesures.date 
) maxi
,
(
SELECT AVG(mesures.valeur) mini
FROM mesures
JOIN plages_horaire ON mesures.id_plage = plages_horaire.id_plage 
WHERE MONTH(mesures.date) = '9' AND YEAR(mesures.date) = '2016' AND mesures.code_station = 'P02SE' AND mesures.id_crit = '1' AND mesures.id_type = '2' 
GROUP BY mesures.date
) mini
,
(
SELECT AVG(mesures.valeur) moy
FROM mesures
JOIN plages_horaire ON mesures.id_plage = plages_horaire.id_plage 
WHERE MONTH(mesures.date) = '9' AND YEAR(mesures.date) = '2016' AND mesures.code_station = 'P02SE' AND mesures.id_crit = '1' AND mesures.id_type = '3' 
GROUP BY mesures.date
) moy
GROUP BY j
```

Problem is that I get what I want excepting values of the 2 last columns are the same at every rows:
[query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gURwI.png)

I believe it's because of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: We'd need to see the structure of these tables and some sample data

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  You are doing massive Cartesian products and then aggregating.

Comment: DB: http://puu.sh/yuDfd/2f68a940d1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see from your query, you don't need the `plage_horaire` table.  You can also simplify the logic greatly by using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT m.date,
       AVG(CASE WHEN m.id_type = 1 THEN m.valeur END) maxi,
       AVG(CASE WHEN m.id_type = 2 THEN m.valeur END) mini,
       AVG(CASE WHEN m.id_type = 3 THEN m.valeur END) maxmoy,
FROM mesures m 
WHERE MONTH(m.date) = 9 AND YEAR(m.date) = 2016 AND
      m.code_station = 'P02SE' AND m.id_crit = 1 AND m.id_type IN (1, 2, 3)    
GROUP BY m.date ;
```

Notice that I also removed the quotes from the numeric constants.  `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` return numbers, so quotes are not appropriate.  I am guessing that the ids are numeric as well.

Comment: i think `AND m.id_type = 1` should be `AND m.id_type IN (1,2,3)`.  (I'd also write the condition for the date range as  `m.date >= '2016-09-01' AND m.date < '2016-10-01'`.

Comment: I need the link with `plage_horaire` because it contains all the data.
I'd like to share the database with you but apart from screenshots...

Comment: @SimonCo . . . Your query is using no values from that table.

Comment: Including a join to `plage_horaire` is only going to affect the query if there are values in `id_plage` column of `mesures` that don't appear in the `id_plage` column of `plage_horaire` table and/or if there are duplicate values in the `id_plage` column of `plage_horaire`. Apart from those conditions, the join to `plage_horaire` doesn't make any difference in the original query.